# iOS: Constrain Safe Area to Superview in nib file

Tags: ios, user-interface, superview, safearealayoutguide

I have a nib file that creates a view for my view controller. I want to use the Safe Area Layout Guide, so I checked off that box under the size inspector.

However, the safe area (highlighted in blue) clearly doesn't match the height of the view.

[image]
I thought perhaps my view was too big, so I tried shrinking it down. But even then, it maintains this weird gap between the top of the view and the top of the safe area.

[image]

How can I constrain the safe area to have the same width/height of the superview?

There is no scroll view. In fact, the hierarchy of my view only includes the safe area and then several labels and 4 `UIImages` (`Species*` - the green boxes).

```
View 
 Safe Area 
 PlacardNE Lbl
 PlacardNW Lbl
 PlacardSE Lbl
 PlacardSW Lbl
 SpeciesNW
 SpeciesNE
 SpeciesSW
 SpeciesSE
 Score Label 
 Score 
 Time
 Instructions Label
 Time Label 
 End Game
```

Constraints
[image]

Comment: Are you using a scroll view or one of its subclasses as a subview of your viewController’s view? If so then go to Attributes inspector of the view controller and uncheck the __automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets__ property.

Comment: no scrollview! Thanks, I'll add that info to my post

Comment: Can you share the view hierarchy and the constraints that you have applied?

Comment: Updated to include!